# What happens to the soul that attained liberation? Is it ever reborn again?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

For example, let us assume a soul that attained liberation at the end of 99 Brahma Years. Now, what happens to soul at the end of a Brahma day? What happens to that soul at the end of 100 years of Brahma which is Mahapralaya?

If the answer is that “No, soul will not be reborn again”, then we all should be liberated isn’t it? What I meant is that neither soul is created or destroyed. So now we have infinite souls and infinite life cycles. But the number of souls that are in material world goes on decreasing as we can safely assume that at least few souls are liberated in 100 Brahma years. So I think there should come a point at which all souls are liberated. What happens then?

If the answer is Yes, I have no more questions.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Liberated Atma is nowhere in touch with Brahma. Don't confuse souls which go back Prakriti unmanifest v Mukta atma. Mukta Atma is different

Comment: Its duplicate here only finite souls are there in one creation cycle of 100 Brahma years based on tatvavada philosophy in that. Some souls attain moksha that is permanent state never return similarly some souls attain andHamas permanent based BG  16.19  some souls will be  in cycle without libration at the end of mahapralaya all souls go to suspended states without awareness of existences but those souls moksha continually experience bilss and andHamas experience continuous pain.

Comment: in next cycle entirely different sets of souls will be considered for next brahmas cycle (including different brahma as the previous brahma had attained moksha) that is why human birth is precious, for moksha sadhana humans have to strive hard that is goal. Even during manvantra, kalpha, some soul maynot get chance to be born human, if soul made to wait one kalpha that is one brahma day, i.e. 14 manvantra, 14 manvantra pralya.. 24 hrs of brahma if sould waits that amounts more than 4.3284 thousand million human years..

Comment: @PrasannaR doesn't the souls which doesn't attain liberation in previous cycle takes birth in fresh cycle from where they left?

Comment: Not all souls attain moksha at the end of Brahma's life of 100 years when the universe is destroyed which is called mahapralaya. Those souls which do not attain moksha at the time of mahapralaya have to wait for the Lord Vishnu to create the universe again. And when Lord Vishnu creates the universe again those souls are reborn again in the universe and continue with their karma where they were interrupted at the last mahapralaya in the previous universe. Those souls just continue with their rebirths in samsara after the universe is created again, it's not that they get moksha.

Comment: see now we need to consider the nature of the soul that is the seed whatever there is in the seed that is what shown outside.. like mongo seed gives mango tree and fruit, similarly if soul nature is rajasic they will be in the cycle for ever because its there seed here we say kaimushti shrusti.. God takes his hand ful of seeds to be planted in the Garden of Eden.. that is brahmanda This seeds can be   from different lot also know only to Vishnu because current devatas need to sent to moksha according to their capacities like sallopiya, sayujaya @AkshayS but this much i heard from Bannaje

Comment: @brahmajijnasa " to wait for the Lord Vishnu to create the universe again" do you have a scriptual reference for this?

Comment: @Wikash_ There are many statements in the scripture which say that Lord Vishnu creates the universe, and also there are statements that the universe is created "again" because if it's not created over and over again throughout eternal time it would mean that the universe was created and destroyed only once in eternal history, and that doesn't seem to be the case as far as Hindu scripture teaches.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa I still do not have an answer.

Comment: @PrasannaR According to what you have said and what I have understood, when one Brahma gets moksha and another brahma takes his position he considers a different set of souls. I have 2 questions here. 1) What happens to the unliberated souls in Previous Brahma's tenure? 2)You told that the new Brahma considers entirely new set of souls. Where did this new set of souls come from? What are they doing previous Brahma's tenure? Thanks a lot for reply and Please correct me If I am wrong

Comment: Here Brahma is new whole godly beings are new, souls are plenty for God to seed, since for this new Brahma cycle new souls will be there all the other souls which had been through the other Brahma cycle Will be in suspended animation without being aware that they being exists

Comment: But from where does the God have souls have to seed? I mean I am pretty sure that souls can neither be created or destroyed. And I think souls which attained God will never return back to the material world. I think what you are referring to this idea that "while some souls are in animated state, others are sent to the material world", is it?. But according to What I have read in BG from 8.17-8.19: this verses refer to "all living beings" manifest and unmanifest, not some set of souls. I hope you would clarify this.

Comment: if we base our premise of no., souls are finite and all the souls are part of the creation  t hen this theory of infinite creation is wrong. but as per BG or whatever vedic statements hinduism believes this creation is inifinite.. too hold this this theory we should can only assume that souls are plenty that are close to infinite for God to create but doesnt create new souls whatever existed he took and seed if take that same souls are in this cycle also means those who did respective shadana and went to moksha

Comment: must come back so this theory is ruled out that same souls are in this cycle, so it can only be different soul .. so that some of the souls can do moksha sadhana and also dush sadhana to get into andhamas so the whole set had to be new not the same.. This manifest and unmanifest meant for one cycle of brahmas life.

Comment: @PrasannaR what happens to people who neither achieve Moskha nor go to Andhatamas. Will they be reborn again in next kalpa? Or will they stay eternally in suspended animation and what do they experience? 50% bliss 50% pain??

Comment: This is more of a mathematical question rather than a religious one.

There are infinite number of souls, even though many souls will get liberated, there will be still infinite number of souls left. So this Samsara will keep on going on and on.

Infinity minus any finite number is infinite. So there will always be infinite number of unliberated souls.

Comment: Vivekachudamani  Verse 6
'vadantu śāstrāṇiyajantu devān...there is no Liberation without the realisation of one’s identity with the Ātman, no, not even in the lifetime of a hundred Brahmas put together. .. may answer your question

Comment: @John they will be reborn based lord vishnu ichha if he thinks that this soul can be born again he will make him born till that time Un liberated can neither experience sawrrow or bliss but without awareness but some frustration will be their of not being born human

Comment: One more point is this souls who are already born as humans they retain the knowledge but hidden otherwise no way explaining child pordigies